# mock object woes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, winapi, cppunit

We have the following problem: a number of classes that we cannot touch but need to unit test them unfortunately the classes are not designed with unit testing in mind so we issues creating mock objects to test the code.

Example:

```
class SomeOtherClass
{
public:
void foo2() {  … }
};

class ClassToTest
{
public:
ClassToTest() {…}
void foo1() { SomeOtherClass A.foo2(); }
};
```

In the above example we would like to test `foo1()` but it needs `foo2()` so we would like to make `foo2()` belong to a mock object (in real life these functions/classes are vastly more complex and involve interaction with hardware configurations etc thus the need for mock objects/functions).

Until now we have done something like this but it is really not optimal because the code seems to have side effects on other unit tests.

```
class MockSomeOtherClass
{
public:
  foo2() { … } // mock function
};

#define SomeOtherClass MockSomeOtherClass

#include “ClassToTest.cpp”
...
```

Is there a better way to do this without changing the original classes (or with minimal changes)? We use CPPUnit for testing.

EDIT: added tag winapi to more clearly describe out environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a product called [Typemock Isolator++](http://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page) that appears to address the issues you have raised.  I have not tried it yet, so can't comment on how well it works or how easy/difficult it is to use.

Unfortunately, you have to give them your email address to try it.  The download is easy enough, but then you are redirected to [this page](http://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-Thank-you) which cheerfully directs you to "Register your software now to get a FREE trial!  Please enter your details including a valid email in order to receive your activation key to start using Isolator++."